# How do I display a table using an explode or is there something else to suggest?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, explode, implode

First I want to explain my application:

I have created an application for my QA work. The application generates a document gets saved as a pdf and added to the server. I have a dynamic table in it that gets save to the database using the implode function separating it as with a comma in the same row as the test case on the database.

It all works fine, but when I want to view the test case I am having trouble to figuring out how to get it to display. I have read plenty of scenarios to use the explode but no luck...

```
<?php include 'app_database/database.php'; ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){

  $step = $_REQUEST['step'];
  $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
  $pass_fail = $_REQUEST['pass_fail'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
  $sql1 ="UPDATE qa_testing_application SET step='".implode(',',$step)."',url='" .  implode(',',$url) . "',pass_fail='" .  implode(',',$pass_fail) . "',comment='" .  implode(',',$comment) . "' WHERE test_case_name='$test_case_name'";
  $result= mysqli_query($database, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($database));
}
?>
```

I am inserting it this way. And i would like to retrieve it from the DB.

I would love to display it as follows:

Please see the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aglk.jpg

At the moment i am trying to test and figure out how to display it:
Not sure how to implement a for or foreach function in here as well if thats needed.

```
$countsteps = 0;
$counturls = 0;
$countpass_fails = 0;
$countcomments = 0;

$test_case_number = '21';
$select_tbl=mysqli_query($database,"select * from qa_testing_application WHERE test_case_number='$test_case_number'");
$result = mysqli_query($database, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($database));
while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
    $step=$fetch->step;
    $url=$fetch->url;
    $pass_fail=$fetch->pass_fail;
    $comment=$fetch->comment;

    $steps=explode(",",$step);
    $urls=explode(",",$url);
    $pass_fails=explode(",",$pass_fail);
    $comments=explode(",",$comment);

    echo '<td>'.$steps[$countsteps++].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$urls[$counturls++]."</td>";
    echo '<td>'.$pass_fails[$countpass_fails++]."</td>";
    echo '<td>'.$comments[$countcomments++]."</td>";

}
```

So how would I get this to display in a table?

**edit**:

Oh and this is the error that I get:

[image]

Comment: Oh and this is the error that i get

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng7fC.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Undefined Offset

This error simply says there is no such key exists into given array or you're trying to fetch a value from non-array variable.

To show data into tabular format, you don't need to explode data coming from db. They are already concatenated.

So to show data from db, modify your code as show below:

```
    $test_case_number = '21';
    $select_tbl=mysqli_query($database,"select * from qa_testing_application WHERE test_case_number='$test_case_number'");
    $result = mysqli_query($database, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($database));

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<th>Step</th><th>Url</th><th>Pass/Fail</th><th>Comment</th>';
    while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
           echo '<tr>';
           echo '<td>'.$fetch->step.'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.$fetch->url.'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.$fetch->pass_fail.'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.$fetch->comment.'</td>';        
           echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You see the thing is that when i inserted the data into mysql i seperated them with a comma so i have to use explode.

Comment: I even tried to use a for each:  $step = explode(',', $step);

and pass it through a foreach as follows:

foreach ($step as $key => $value) {
            echo "<td style='background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:left;'>" .$value . "</td>";
        }

And i get the following results which is not correct:

123

2222

33333

But now how do i get all 4 collumns "step, url, pass_fail, and comment" to do the exact same and make a table

Comment: `$step = explode(',', $step);
        $url = explode(',', $url);
        $pass_fail = explode(',', $pass_fail);
        $comment = explode(',', $comment);

`

Comment: `<?php
            foreach ($step as $key => $value) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $key+1 ; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $url ; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $value ; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $value ; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $value ; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php }  ?>
                `